# Jquery is not working when i try to use it for google custom search?

Tags: jquery

In my case, jQuery is not working. I don't know where I am wrong. It can be confliction with some other js files but not sure. See below screenshot.

[image]

In this screen shot you are seeing google custom search box which is ajax based. My problem is when i click on search box then bottom Premium sales jobs contaner should be hidden. For this i have used this jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gsc-search-button").click(function(){
        $("#container_table").hide();
    });
)};
```

I have included jQuery library with correct path. I have also used `alert()` after `document.ready` to check it is working or not..But its not working.

```
.gsc-search-button is the class of search button.
#container_table is the id of that table which I want to hide.
```

The search data will be load into like div which is initially look like this : 
`<div id="cse">Loading</div>` and after search `iframe` placed into this div and replaced Loading String.

I have also tried below javascript code :

```
if(document.getElementById('cse').innerHTML != "Loading") {
  document.getElementById('#container_table').style.display = "none";
  }
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't clear, actually.

Comment: I knw its so confusing..actualy i have used some other js files..hope may be jquery is not working by conflicting to those files. Actualy I want to use Jquery nad then with the help of jquery i want to hide contaner_table when i click on search button. As i can't add in search button element as its coming from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the CSS style selectors in jQuery with the ID in the following code:

```
document.getElementById('#container_table')
```

It might work if you remove the '#' symbol:

```
document.getElementById('container_table')
```

But another way that would clear the element with "cse" identity would be

```
$('#cse').text('')
```

Comment: @bernhard..when i try to alert with in if then alert box will not show.

Comment: `.empty()` is the best way to empty an element with jQuery.

Comment: @bernard thanks for reply but actualy jquery code is not running..if it runs then evrything will be fine..may be it conflicts with other js files..there are many js files are using in single file..